# Is it safe to save JWT on UserState/Azure Blob Storage with MS Bot Framework?

Tags: azure, botframework

I have an API Service where users can manage ToDo's and I want to create a Bot to allow Signed Up users to create ToDos on their accounts using my Slack Bot.

The steps that I'm thinking of are:

1. My Bot will show the user a message asking him to authenticate
2. The API will send to the user's mobile phone a verification code
3. The user will write that code in the chat with my Bot
4. My bot will make an HTTP request to the API Service to validate that code
5. Then the API will authenticate the user and generate a JSON Web Token for that user.
6. The API will return this JWT to my Bot
7. And my bot will storage this token using Azure Blob Storage.

Now, when the user wants to create a ToDo, the steps should be the following:

1. The user enters something like "Pay bill tomorrow".
2. My bot will retrieve the user JWT from the Azure Blob Storage
3. Then my bot will make an HTTP request to the API service using this token
4. And the API can authenticate the user by checking the Token and create the ToDO.

By doing that, I'll be able to keep the user logged in for 1 year and the user can request the bot to create ToDos on their behalf without the need to authenticate again during this period.

However, I don't know if I'm missing some security issues in this process.

Is there a better way to do that?

thanks!

Comment: refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/benchmark/azure/baselines/bot-service-security-baseline?toc=%2Fazure%2Fbot-service%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-bot-service-4.0 on the general security baselines which apply to azure bot service.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to [Bot-authentication](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples#authentication-samples) that demonstrates how to integrate OAuth providers for user authenticated flows. Bot Service collects no customer data for service improvement.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ram-msft, thanks for the answer. In my case, I can't use this solution because my backend does not have an OAuth integration with any identity provider. But thank you very much